# My Django App only works on heroku when server is running locally

Tags: django, heroku

I have built an app using react and django. After deploying the app on heroku, when I open it the frontend works fine. However when i try to do any action that sends requests to the backend I get errors. The only time the requests work fine is when the django backend is running locally. I hsve been looking allover for solutions and have not been able to find any solutions. In my settings.py The heroku domain name is added to the allowed hosts

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', 'barkbnb-demo.herokuapp.com']
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction on where to begin looking for solving the issue that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your request string in React app when you call your backend. It looks like it uses local address there.